# RequireJS - Own module with two ways loading

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd

I'm trying to create a module that can be loaded asynchronously (AMD) and via HTML script tag. I added this construction to my module (I took it from jQuery source code):

```
if ( typeof define === "function" && define.amd ) { 
    define( "mymodule", ['googlemaps'], function(google) {
       return myModule; 
    }); 
}

myModule = function() {
    // here code uses "google" 
}
```

My module depends on Google Maps API so if I load my module via HTML script tag it works. But if my module was loaded asynchronously variable "google" only available in "define" block. Are there any ways to pass this variable to global scope (for my module file)?

Comment: var GoogleAPI = require('googlemaps'); ?

Comment: why can't you require() googlemaps too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(function(global, factory) {
  if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) { // requirejs
    return define(['googlemaps'], factory);
  } else if (typeof exports === 'object') {    // nodejs
    return module.exports = factory(require('googlemaps'));
  } else {  // html
    return global['Odysseus'] = factory(global['googlemaps']);
  }
})(this, function(GoogleAPI) {
    ...
    return myModule; 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can declare global variable `GoogleAPI` and append value from define to it

```
var GoogleAPI;
define( "mymodule", ['googlemaps'], function(google) {
    GoogleAPI = google;
    return myModule; 
});
```